# Generalized elements and limits

Tags: category-theory

According to Awodey's *Category Theory*, in any category $\mathbf C$, a generalized element of an object $C$ is an arrow with codomain $C$; denote with $\operatorname {Gen}(C)$ the set of the generalized elements of $C$, that obviously can be extended to a functor. For an object $D$, denote also  with $\operatorname{Gen}_D(C)$ the set of generalized elements of $C$ with domain $D$; so its extension to a functor is just the representable $\mathbf C(D,-)$.

Let $J:\mathbf I\to \mathbf C$ be a diagram . Then the fact that $\mathbf C(D,-)$ preserves limits means that $\operatorname{Gen}_D(\operatorname{lim}J)\cong \operatorname{lim}(\operatorname{Gen}_D\circ J)$, as sets. To make this clearer, for another object $C'$, $\operatorname{Gen}_D(C\times C')\cong \operatorname{Gen}_D(C)\times \operatorname{Gen}_D(C')$; but I would say that this bijection, that surely holds for all $D$, holds also dropping the subscript $D$: $\operatorname{Gen}(C\times C')\cong \operatorname{Gen}(C)\times \operatorname{Gen}(C')$. *Is there an elegant\interesting way of proving this in general,* i.e. $\operatorname{Gen}(\operatorname{lim}J)\cong \operatorname{lim}(\operatorname{Gen}\circ J)$?

What I thought is that $\operatorname{Gen}$ is a functor equivalent to $\coprod _{D\in\operatorname{ob}(\mathbf C)}(\operatorname{Gen}_D) $, defined extending the objectwise coproduct to a functor. Then $$\operatorname{Gen}(\operatorname{lim}J)\cong \coprod _{D\in\operatorname{ob}(\mathbf C)}(\operatorname{Gen}_D(\operatorname{lim}J))\cong \coprod _{D\in\operatorname{ob}(\mathbf C)}(\operatorname{lim}(\operatorname{Gen}_D\circ J))\cong \operatorname{lim}(\coprod _{D\in\operatorname{ob}(\mathbf C)}(\operatorname{Gen}_D\circ J)) \cong \operatorname{lim}(\coprod _{D\in\operatorname{ob}(\mathbf C)}(\operatorname{Gen}_D)\circ J)\cong\operatorname{lim}(\operatorname{Gen}\circ J)).$$ Explicitely, the third bijection holds if (in the general case) given a family of diagrams $(H_s:\mathbf I\to\mathbf{Set})_{s\in S}$, $$\lim_{i\in I}(\coprod_{s\in S}(H_s(i)))\cong \coprod_{s\in S}(\lim_{i\in I}(H_s(i))).$$ *Do you confirm that indeed it is true?* I'm not certain, because the coproduct is a colimit, so it doesn't necessarily commutes with limits, but in this case it seems to hold. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is obviously false. Consider the cardinality of these sets. You would be claiming something to the effect that $x \times y + z \times w = (x + z) \times (y + w)$.

Comment: @ZhenLin thanks, I don't know why I was convinced that $\operatorname{Gen}$ preserved limits. Just intuitively, in $\operatorname{Gen}(C)\times \operatorname{Gen}(C')$ the only pairs $(u,v)$ that correspond to an element of $\operatorname{Gen}(C\times C')$ are those with $\operatorname{dom}(u)=\operatorname{dom}(v)$, so $\operatorname{Gen}(C)\times \operatorname{Gen}(C')$ and $\operatorname{Gen}(C\times C')$ shouldn't be in bijection. (It should be easy to make an example with finite categories, using cardinalities as you suggested)